# How can I set width to th of table, and td below will inherit width?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to set width to my th and want to td's below to inherit width from th, I tried to set width to th but it does not work.

Comment: what are we working with? please post code.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nx7h4dmL/ @Mech

Comment: @NurdauletShamilov do you want to a fix width of th ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `min-width` from table and add `width:100%`. Set width for `th`, it will work

```css
    div {
      border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12);
      border-radius: 4px;

      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      display: inline-flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      overflow-x: auto;
    }
    table {
      font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
      /* min-width: 100%; */
      border-collapse: collapse;

      width: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
    thead tr {
      border: 0;
    }
    tr {
      border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    }
    th {
      font-weight: 500;
      height: 56px;
      line-height: 1.375rem;
      letter-spacing: .0071428571em;
      width: 8rem
    }
    td {
      font-weight: 400;
      height: 52px;
      line-height: 1.25rem;
      letter-spacing: .0178571429em;
    }
    td, th {
      padding: 0px 16px;
      text-align: left;
      font-size: .875rem;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;  
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ФИО</th>
        <th>Статус по Т.Д.</th>
        <th>Статус работника</th>
        <th>Должность</th>
        <th style="
">Подразделение</th>
        <th>Вид занятости</th>
        <th>Ставка</th>
        <th>Трудовой договор</th>
        <th>Приказ</th>
        <th>Основание</th>
        <th>Период работы</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">Иванов Иван Иванович<arrow-button-component></arrow-button-component>
        </td>
        <td>Действующий</td>
        <td>На работе</td>
        <td>руководитель отдела разработки</td>
        <td>Департмент информационых технологии</td>
        <td>Основое</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since,Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since</td>
        <td>Приказ о расторжении дополнительного соглашения</td>
        <td>Заявление. Статьи 34 и 36 Трудового кодекса Республики Казахстан</td>
        <td>с 15.11.2019 по 23.06.2020</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Действующий</td>
        <td>На работе</td>
        <td>руководитель отдела разработки</td>
        <td>Департмент информационых технологии</td>
        <td>Основое</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since,Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since</td>
        <td>Приказ о расторжении дополнительного соглашения</td>
        <td>Заявление. Статьи 34 и 36 Трудового кодекса Республики Казахстан</td>
        <td>с 15.11.2019 по 23.06.2020</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Расторгнут</td>
        <td>Уволен/а</td>
        <td>руководитель отдела разработки</td>
        <td>Департмент информационых технологии</td>
        <td>Основое</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since,Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since</td>
        <td>Приказ о расторжении дополнительного соглашения</td>
        <td>Заявление. Статьи 34 и 36 Трудового кодекса Республики Казахстан</td>
        <td>с 15.11.2019 по 23.06.2020</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">Анна Иванович<arrow-button-component></arrow-button-component>
        </td>
        <td>Действующий</td>
        <td>Уволен/а</td>
        <td>руководитель отдела разработки</td>
        <td>Департмент информационых технологии</td>
        <td>Основое</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since</td>
        <td>Приказ о расторжении дополнительного соглашения</td>
        <td>Заявление. Статьи 34 и 36 Трудового кодекса Республики Казахстан</td>
        <td>с 15.11.2019 по 23.06.2020</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Алишер Казболдинов<arrow-button-component></arrow-button-component>
        </td>
        <td>Действующий</td>
        <td>На работе</td>
        <td>руководитель отдела разработки</td>
        <td>Департмент информационых технологии</td>
        <td>Основое</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since,Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since</td>
        <td>Приказ о расторжении дополнительного соглашения</td>
        <td>Заявление. Статьи 34 и 36 Трудового кодекса Республики Казахстан</td>
        <td>с 15.11.2019 по 23.06.2020</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Расторгнут</td>
        <td>Уволен/а</td>
        <td>руководитель отдела разработки</td>
        <td>Департмент информационых технологии</td>
        <td>Основое</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since,Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since</td>
        <td>Приказ о расторжении дополнительного соглашения</td>
        <td>Заявление. Статьи 34 и 36 Трудового кодекса Республики Казахстан</td>
        <td>с 15.11.2019 по 23.06.2020</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


</div>
```